# How can i obtain the equivalent conditions in Python for this For loop in C

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

I am trying to write a code in python which is written in C++, while converting the loops of C++ to python I am facing diffculities.

```cpp
for(int len = 1; len < n; len++){
            for(int i = 0; i + len < n; i++){
                   // bla bla bla code
               }
            }
```

How can i write the inner for loop in python ??
Any generalized approach which can work in every scenario ??
If the Question is duplicate one sorry for this I couldn't know what and how to search in google about this.

Can I please get some help in this problem from you. Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If `s` is of length `3`, in the first iteration `x` is `0`, so what is `3 - 0`, and what is the last valid *index* of `s`…?

Comment: Also note that according to your logic, `((` would be a "balanced" string. Also note that you're `return`ing in every loop iteration, meaning only the very first iteration is ever going to complete and the function will end after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: `for x in range(len(s))` `x` goes though all integers in range `[0, len(s))`, so its first value will be *zero*. Here: `s[len(s)-x]` when `x == 0`, the index will equal `len(s)`, which is invalid, because the greatest valid index for a string of length `len(s)>0` is `len(s)-1`.

How to fix: that's an off-by-one error, and you probably meant `s[len(s)-x-1]`.